# Элементы, которых нет в другом массиве

Tags: php

Есть два массива. Маленький, и большой. Как узнать каких элементов из большого нет в маленьком?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный вопрос, можно было бы легко загуглите самому и получить чёткий ответ. 
А ответ: использовать специальную функцию. 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Ответ - ссылка!